# Login React + Express + mongoDB doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have an issue with the login authentication in my project. I connected my react front end with my express back end, but when I try to login with valid credentials, it gets stuck in an error seems like it can't read properly the value I'm passing in my form input.

Here's my LogIn page:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { signin } from '../actions/authAction';
    import { clearErrors } from '../actions/errAction';

    import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Input, Alert } from 'reactstrap'
    import TopCont from '../components/TopCont'

    class Signin extends Component {
        state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            msg: null
        };

        static propTypes = {
            isAuth: PropTypes.bool,
            signin: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            err: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
            clearErrors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
        };

        componentDidMount(){
            this.props.clearErrors();
        }

        componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
            const { err } = this.props;

            if(err !== prevProps.err) {
                if(err.id === 'LOGIN_FAIL'){
                    this.setState({ msg: err.msg.msg });
                } else {
                    this.setState({ msg: null });
                }
            }
        };

        onChange = e => {
            this.setState({ 
                [e.target.email]: e.target.value,
                [e.target.password]: e.target.value
            });
        };

        onSubmit = e => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const { email, password } = this.state;

            const user = {
                email,
                password
            };
            
            this.props.signin(user);

            /* this.props.push('/dashboard'); */
        };

        render() {
            return (
            <>
                <TopCont>
                    <div className="signin-cont">
                        <h1>Accedi</h1>

                        {this.state.msg ? <Alert color="danger">{this.state.msg}</Alert> : null }

                        <Form className="signin-form-cont" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Input className="signin-form" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mario.rossi@prova.it" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            </FormGroup>

                            <FormGroup>
                                <Input className="signin-form" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            </FormGroup>

                            <Button className="sign-btn">Accedi</Button>
                        </Form>

                        <p>Non hai ancora un account? <Link to="/signup">Registrati</Link></p>                  
                    </div>
                </TopCont>
            </>
            )
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        isAuth: state.auth.isAuth,
        err: state.err
    });

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { signin, clearErrors })(Signin);
```

Here is my Action:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { returnErrors } from './errAction';
import  { AUTH_ERROR, LOGIN_FAIL } from '../actions/types';

    export const signin = ({ email, password }) => dispatch => {
        const  config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };

        const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

        axios.post('/api/auth', body, config)
            .then(res => dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            }))
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'LOGIN_FAIL'));
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGIN_FAIL
                });
            });
    };
```

And here is my Auth API:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    const config = require('config');
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');

    const User = require('../../models/User');

    //@action POST api/auth
    //@descr auth user
    //@access Public
    router.post('/', (req, res) => {
        const { email, password } = req.body

        if( !email || !password ) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Enter all fields."});
        }

        User.findOne({ email })
            .then(user => {
                if(!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Nessun profilo trovato con questa email"});

                bcrypt.compare( password, user.password )
                    .then(isMatch => {
                        if(!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Password errata!"});

                        jwt.sign(
                            { id: user.id },
                            config.get('jwtSecret'),
                            { expiresIn: 10800 }, 
                            (err, token) => {
                                if(err) throw err;

                                res.json({
                                    token,
                                    user: {
                                        id: user.id,
                                        name: user.name,
                                        surname: user.surname,
                                        email: user.email,
                                        userPlus: user.userPlus
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        )
                    })
            })
    });

    //@action GET api/auth/user
    //@descr GET user data
    //@access Private
    router.get('/user', auth, (req, res) => {
        User.findById(req.user.id)
            .select('-password')
            .then(user => res.json(user));
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

If I try to get rid of all the errors controls my server return this error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null`

The strange thing is that if I try to register a new user (with an almost identical component and server-side method) there are no problems and it authenticates too with no problems.

Someone knows how can I fix this issue?

Comment: your onChange is not good

Comment: Try console.log email and password in onSubmit.
See if you get the expected values there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your onChange Function from this:

```
onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ 
        [e.target.email]: e.target.value,
        [e.target.password]: e.target.value
    });
};
```

to this:

```
onChange = e => this.setState(prevState => ({
                ...prevState, 
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            }));
```

Comment: Thanks now it works! I just pass `[e.target.name]: e.target.value,` inside this.setState. I thought I have to target every single date from my form.